Implementation of Apple Pay not compliant with Apple's UI guidelines in React Native app using react-native-square-in-app-payments
I'm developing a React Native application that utilizes Apple Pay as a purchasing mechanism, employing the react-native-square-in-app-payments library. However, upon submitting my app for review on the App Store, I received a message stating that my Apple Pay implementation does not adhere to Apple's user interface guidelines. Specifically, the Apple Pay button I've integrated doesn't follow Apple's approved designs.
I'm seeking guidance on how to rectify this issue and implement the Apple Pay button in accordance with these guidelines within my React Native application. I'm using my custom component to display the Apple Pay button. Any advice or resources on how to achieve this correctly would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

show us the button you've implemented so we can give you advice>
